# HTML 5 geolocation api shows wrong position

Tags: api, geolocation, location

I really searched hard for it and I didn't find an answer. The problem I am facing is, that I programmed an application for an audiotour through a city based on open street map and the geolocation api. 
So the problem I am facing is, that, if I access the application via G3 from my iphone I sometimes get a totaly inadequate location, (often the same, somewhere in the city), but if I use the google maps app I get an ecaxt position. I don't understand the fact, that if I make the same call from safari and from an app, I get different results.
I use 'navigator.geolocation.watchPosition' with the following options:
enableHighAccuracy: true,
timeout: 50000,
maximumAge: 0

I would really apreciate it, if someone who also faced the problem, and has an solution for this, would help me. What also happend is, that if I opend the web application and my iphone turns in power safe mode and I reactivate it, the position gets totally crazy.

Comment: This question is off-topic unless you include your code.

Answer (score 0):

My Code is really long and complicated, but maybe this helps:

```
options = {
                enableHighAccuracy: true,
                timeout: 50000,
                maximumAge: 0
    };


watchID = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( function(position) {
            map.setCenter(lonLat, zoom );
            }, function(error) { alert('Cannot determine your location! Check if you enabled geolocation for your browser.');}, options);

watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition( function(position) { Here is the function!}
                geolocationError,
                {
                    enableHighAccuracy: true,
                    timeout: 50000,
                    maximumAge: 0
                }
            } 
);
```